# How to set marker size/color in go.Scattergeo?

Tags: python, plotly, figure

I want to set the maker size or color according to a list of values. The result of the markers should shown as the follwing scatterplot for example:
[image]

Another example is this:
[image]

My code looks like this:

```
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scattergeo(
        #lon = tmp[1],
        #lat = tmp[0],
        mode = 'markers',
        lon = long,
        lat = lat,
        ))
fig.update_layout(
        geo_scope = 'europe',
        width = 1200,
        height = 800,
)
fig.update_geos(showsubunits=True)
fig.show()
```

My return:
[image]

What do I have to add to manipulate each point according to my list of values *counts*?

Comment: The size is specified by the size of the marker, please refer to the examples in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/bubble-maps/#united-states-bubble-map). `marker = dict(size = df_sub['pop']/scale,...)`